# Solr Spatial search - How do I sort documents first by an explicit match and then by distance?

Tags: solr, spatial-query

I'm trying to determine how to sort or score the results of my query so that documents with an explicit match on a particular field will be returned first, followed by other matching documents in ascending distance.

Following the examples used in Solr's Spatial tutorials, let's say that I have a couple Stores, which looks something like this (pseudo):

```
<Store>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Coords>10,-15</Coords>
  <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
  <ServiceArea>
    <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
    <PostalCode>23456</PostalCode>
  </ServiceArea> 
</Store>

<Store>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Coords>11,-16</Coords>
  <PostalCode>23456</PostalCode>
  <ServiceArea>
    <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
    <PostalCode>23456</PostalCode>
  </ServiceArea> 
</Store>
```

So, two stores.  Each in their own postal codes, and each servicing each other's postal codes.  Now I want to query something to the effect of:

```
Find stores which service PostalCode 12345
Ordered by stores in PostalCode 12345 first
Then ordered by ascending distance from PostalCode 12345
```

I'm trying to keep this to using the `StandardQueryParser`, and if boosting is involved it needs to be defined in the query, rather than the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sort specification, use:

> sort=query({!field f=PostalCode v=12345})+desc,geodist()+asc

You can sort on fields, score, and function queries.  Function queries opens up a lot of possibilities, and the "query()" function query opens up even more, as seen above.  query() will return the score of the query within it, which in this case is a search for a field having a certain value.  I chose to use the 'field' query parser but you just as well could do {!v="PostalCode:12345"}.

By the way, don't forget the other parameters for geodist(), like 'pt' and 'sfield'.